# NodeJs cherrio library parse xml

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm using cherrio to parse an xml file. I've loaded the file and also I've set xmlMode: true.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(rawAssertion, {
    xmlMode: true
});
```

My xml is something like bellow:

```
<myNamespace:myTagData>
    <myNamespace:myTag>data inside this node</myNamespace:myTag>
</myNamespace:myTagData>
```

My problem is that the specific node that I'm searching for has a namespace and it seems that doing a simple search doesn't find my node. I tried the following:

```
var tagInfo= $('myTag');
console.log(tagInfo.text());
```

When printing the text value, the result is empty string. As I understood this can suggest that the element was now found in the xml.

I've tried to add the namspace when searching the node but I received an error: SyntaxError: unmatched pseudo-class.

Note that I can access the text of xml nodes that doesn't have namespace.

How to search for an xml node that has an namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working by adding the namespace. The only thing to keep in mind is that you must escape the colons:

```
var tagInfo= $('myNamespace\\:myTag');
console.log(tagInfo.text());
```

Comment: And if there's no namespace?